# Azure Site to Site VPN add a new connection

Tags: azure, azure-networking

We already have a site to site VPN connected  Virtual Network Gateway  and local network gateway already exists,
Now some other region needs to be add which has Public ip of XXX.xxx.xxx.xxx how do I add this?

Comment: What kind of virtual network gateway do you have configured?  Certificate auth? EAP?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has docs for a `multi-site` configuration of a S2S connection. You can reference the docs here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-multi-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal

Without more specifics on the question, this would be the best place to start. Let us know if it is what you're looking for!